# Stress/Perfomance and Load test on website located at web server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, testing

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC Web Application, which will be deployed to a server.

May I know how I can carry out:

- Performance, stress test and load test for each page
- Performance, stress test and load test for specific user actions and
  HTTP Post pages

Note: There are no remote debugging feature for the web hosting plan I use

In addition to that, I would like to know how to carry out the above tests without access to the code, eg: I want to perform above same tests for ebay, amazon etc

Comment: You can use [JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/) to perform load tests. No remote debugging or code access required.